# Intent not passing my data

Tags: android

I'm trying to send 2 parameter from one activity to another,but for some reason only one of the parameter is passed. what could it be?

Sending Activity:

```
showActivity(OrderActivity.class, new Pair("CUSTOMER_ID", customerId), new Pair("CUSTOMER_TYPE", customerType));
```

Receiving Activity : The customer id is showing 0 but the type data is got

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    long customerId = extras.getLong("CUSTOMER_ID");
    int customerType = extras.getInt("CUSTOMER_TYPE");
    Log.d("===customer ", " id : " + customerId + "  type : " + customerType);
```

the `showActivity` looks like this

```
protected void showActivity(Class<? extends BaseKaizenActivity> clazz, Pair<String, Object> ... parameters) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, clazz);
    if (parameters != null) {
        for (Pair<String, Object> pair : parameters) {
            if (pair.second instanceof Integer) {
                intent.putExtra(pair.first, (Integer)pair.second);  
            }
            else if (pair.second instanceof Parcelable) {
                intent.putExtra(pair.first, (Parcelable)pair.second);
            }
        }
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Post the full code of sending data in sending activity?

Comment: Y can't you simply use getExtra and putExtra?

Comment: Can you post detail of showActivity()?

Comment: @topxebec i think it has got to do with the long which is the type of the customerID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (pair.second instanceof Integer) {
                intent.putExtra(pair.first, (Integer)pair.second);  
            }
            else if (pair.second instanceof Parcelable) {
                intent.putExtra(pair.first, (Parcelable)pair.second);
            }
```

Seems like you fogot to write a clause for Long.It gose neither of if nor else if,so has not been put into extradata.

Comment: so it goes something like this.

`if (pair.second instanceof Integer) {
     intent.putExtra(pair.first, (Integer)pair.second); 
    }
    else if (pair.second instanceof Long) {
     intent.putExtra(pair.first, (Long)pair.second); 
    }
    else if (pair.second instanceof Parcelable) {
     intent.putExtra(pair.first, (Parcelable)pair.second);
    }

Answer (score 0):

why are u using that? just use put and get method of intent its very simple.eg.

```
intent.putExtra("backPressed", true);
getIntent().getBooleanExtra("backPressed", false);
```

this is my working code and got no problem.